# How to create a running total- Python

Tags: python

This code asks a user to enter an 8 digit GTIN to place an order for a product. Once the quantity of the product is entered I write it into a separate (empty) receipt file. Once they finish ordering products the program stops and upon opening the Order Receipt file you can see the products ordered.

Once the products are ordered I would like my receipt to display the total order bill (product_price) added up. In order to do this I need to create a running total but I do not understand other tutorials.

```
receipt_out = open("Order Receipt.txt","w")
go_again = True
while go_again==True:
    file = open("GTIN_Description.txt","r")

    keep_asking = False
    while keep_asking==False:
        gtin = input("Enter GTIN: ")
        keep_asking = gtin.isdigit()

    found = False
    keep_asking = True
    while keep_asking == True:
        for fileline in file:
            linecontent=fileline.split('\t')
            if gtin == linecontent[0]:
                product_name = linecontent[1]
                gtinprice = float(linecontent[2])
                quantity = int(input("Quantity of item: "))
                price = gtinprice * quantity
                product_price = "£{0:.2f}".format(price)
                print (linecontent[1],"for", product_price)
                output_to_receipt = ("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n").format(gtin, product_name, quantity, gtinprice, product_price)
                print(output_to_receipt)
                receipt_out.write(output_to_receipt)
                found = True
```

(I want to create a running total here where all the overall product_price are added together from the User's input to be displayed on a receipt)

```
        if found == False:
            print ("GTIN not found")

        more = input("Input 'Y' to continue or 'N' to quit window and be supplied with a receipt of your orders: ")
        if more.lower().strip()== "y":
            keep_asking = False
        elif more.lower().strip()=="n":
            receipt_out.write(output_to_receipt)
            receipt_out.close()
            print("Thank you for ordering with Computer Warehouse")
```

Many thanks
    ~rn01

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
found = False
keep_asking = True
total_price = 0.0  # <--
while keep_asking == True:
    for fileline in file:
        linecontent=fileline.split('\t')
        if gtin == linecontent[0]:
            product_name = linecontent[1]
            gtinprice = float(linecontent[2])
            quantity = int(input("Quantity of item: "))
            price = gtinprice * quantity
            total_price += price                 # <--
            product_price = "£{0:.2f}".format(price)
            print (linecontent[1],"for", product_price)
            output_to_receipt = ("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n").format(gtin, product_name, quantity, gtinprice, product_price)
            print(output_to_receipt, "\t(total: {})".format(total_price))   # <--
            receipt_out.write(output_to_receipt)
            found = True
```

Comment: You'll probably want to move the total to the end of his code before he closes out the file. Unless he means to have a running total after each line of the receipt? But this was essentially my answer so I'm not going to create a duplicate